# How do I create a table where the user can change the value which effects a result in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, excel

I have just started learning angularJS. I have been given a Excel spread-sheet by my boss who wants me to basically put that onto the website.

In Excel, cells in the spread sheet can be changed which effect other cells using formulas.

In my application so far, I have a table. For example:

```js
var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);

app1.controller('ctrl1', function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- AngularJs controller -->
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
  <!-- TABLE -->
  <main class="container-fluid wrapper">
    <section class="row bg-white">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <!-- Table header -->
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Length</th>
                <th>Width</th>
                <th>Area</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Kilos</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- Table body -->
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Flax Door Half Hour</td>
                <td>2040</td>
                <td>926</td>
                <td>1.89</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>41.56</td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
```

How do I make each cell editable? 
How do I do excel like formulas, such as **=SUM(E8*F8)*22**

Answer (score 0):

this is demo: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/#/demo/spreadsheet

you can download from this: https://github.com/thelgevold/angular-2-samples

Component Code:

```
import {Component, Input, AfterViewChecked} from '@angular/core';
import {NgModel} from '@angular/common';
import {SpreadsheetModel} from './spreadsheetModel';
import {KeyMap} from './key-map';
import {HeaderRowService} from './header-row-service';
@Component({
    selector: 'spreadsheet',
    templateUrl: './components/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html'
})
export class Spreadsheet implements AfterViewChecked {
    model:SpreadsheetModel;
    @Input() rows:Number;
    @Input() columns:Number;
    constructor(){
        this.model = new SpreadsheetModel(10,4);
        this.header = HeaderRowService.createHeader(this.model.rows[0].columns.length);
        this.visibleRows = this.getVisibleRows();
    }
    getHeader(){
        return HeaderRowService.createHeader(this.model.rows[0].columns.length);
    }
    navigate($event){
        this.model.navigate($event.keyCode);
        this.visibleRows = this.getVisibleRows();
    }
    ngAfterViewChecked(){
        let cell = document.getElementById(this.model.current.rowIndex + '-' + this.model.current.columnIndex);
        cell.focus();
    }
    getVisibleRows(){
        return this.model.rows.filter((row) => row.rowIndex >= this.model.start && row.rowIndex < this.model.end);
    }
    getActive(col){
        if(col === this.model.current){
            return 'active-cell';
        }
    }
}
```

Model Code

```
import {KeyMap} from './key-map';
import {Row} from './row';
import {Column} from './column';
export class SpreadsheetModel{
    rows:Array<Row>;
    current:Column;
    start:number;
    end:number;
    constructor(public rowCount, public columnCount){
        this.rows = [];
        this.start = 0;
        this.end = rowCount;
        for(let i = 0; i < this.rowCount; i++){
            this.rows.push(new Row(i,this.columnCount));
        }
        this.current = this.rows[0].columns[0];
    }
    selectColumn(col){
        this.current = col;
    }
    navigate(keyCode){
        const navDirection = KeyMap.getNavigationDirection(keyCode);
        if(navDirection.down){
            this.ensureRow();
            this.current = this.rows[this.current.rowIndex + 1].columns[this.current.columnIndex];
            this.adjustRowRangeDownward();
        }
        if(navDirection.up){
            if(this.current.rowIndex === 0){
                return;
            }
            this.current = this.rows[this.current.rowIndex - 1].columns[this.current.columnIndex];
            this.adjustRowRangeUpward();
        }
        if(navDirection.left){
            if(this.current.columnIndex === 0){
                return;
            }
            this.current = this.rows[this.current.rowIndex].columns[this.current.columnIndex - 1];
        }
        if(navDirection.right){
            if(this.current.columnIndex === this.columnCount - 1){
                return;
            }
            this.current = this.rows[this.current.rowIndex].columns[this.current.columnIndex + 1];
        }
    }
    adjustRowRangeUpward(){
        if(this.current.rowIndex < this.start){
            this.shiftRowsBy(-1);
        }
    }
    adjustRowRangeDownward(){
        if(this.current.rowIndex === this.end){
            this.shiftRowsBy(1);
        }
    }
    shiftRowsBy(offset){
        this.start = this.start + offset;
        this.end = this.end + offset;
    }
    ensureRow(){
        if(this.current.rowIndex + 1 >= this.rows.length){
            this.rows.push(new Row(this.current.rowIndex + 1,this.columnCount));
        }
    }
}
```

Entities

```
import {Column} from './column';
//Row
export class Row{
    columns:Array;
    constructor(public rowIndex, public columnCount){
        this.columns = [];
        for(let j = 0; j < this.columnCount; j++){
            this.columns.push(new Column(j,this.rowIndex));
        }
    }
}

//Column
export class Column{
    cellValue:String;
    constructor(public columnIndex,public rowIndex){
        this.cellValue = '';
    }
}
```

View (template code HTML):

```
<table id="spreadsheet">
    <tr>
        <td class="row-number-column"></td>
        <td class="columnHeader" *ngFor="let columnHeader of header">{{columnHeader}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of visibleRows">
        <td class="row-number-column">{{row.rowIndex}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let col of row.columns">
            <input  data-id="{{col.rowIndex}}-{{col.columnIndex}}" [value]="col.cellValue" (input)="col.cellValue = $event.target.value" (click)="model.selectColumn(col)" (keyup)="navigate($event)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it can help you. I copy from this http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/virtualized-spreadsheet-component-in-angular-2.0

Answer (score 0):

This is long to achieve, especially the formula thing but the following can give you a starting point:

Each editable value inside TD's should be [a directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

```
<td><super-edit value="2040"></super-edit></td>
```

This way the directive can handle the state of the element which I called `editMode`

When you click on a TD element, the editMode is set to true and an input is made visible using [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

The value of the TD element and the input field are linked using [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)
This way modifying the value inside the input will update the value of the TD.

To leave the `editMode` I chose to hide the input when you click outside of it using [ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)

```
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Flax Door Half Hour</td>
        <td><super-edit value="2040"></super-edit></td>
        <td><super-edit value="926"></super-edit></td>
        <td><super-edit value="1.89"></super-edit></td>
        <td><super-edit value="1"></super-edit></td>
        <td><super-edit value="41.56"></super-edit></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

function superEdit() {
    return {
    scope: {},
    restrict: 'E',
    bindToController: {
        value: '='
    },
    template: [
      '<span ng-if="!c.editMode" ng-click="c.editMode = true">{{c.value}}</span>',
      '<input type="text" ng-model="c.value" ng-if="c.editMode" ng-blur="c.editMode = false">'
    ].join(''),
    controller: SuperController,
    controllerAs: 'c'
  }
}
function SuperController() {
    this.editMode = false;
}
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('superEdit', superEdit);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5430/)